# Is there an accessor function for topCalc data?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

As of 4.7, the downloadDataFormatter() has been deprecated and replaced with accessor attributes. But i don't see a way to apply an accessor to the topCalc data ?

previously it was :

downloadDataFormatter:function(info) { info.calcs.top.FieldName = ... ; }

now ?

Comment: It seems the column accessor() is called for the topCalc values, so is there a flag to indicate that its a topCalc row, rather than a normal data row ?

Answer (score 0):

They use the same accessor as the normal cells.

In the v4.8 release Row Component / Calc Component will be passed into the accessor as the 5th argument and will allow you to determine which type of value is being processed.